# How to combine the functions of having the ability to select multiple items from a drop down list and hide columns based on values of said list?

Tags: excel, vba, list

I have a list that is based on the header names of columns and am able to hide all but the selected column in the list based on the current coding I have. However, this only works for one selection from the list at a time. I would like to be able to select multiple column titles from the list and all of the selected columns remain visible while the rest are hidden.

I attempted to combine code that would let me select multiple items from the list with the existing code that allows me to hide all but the selected column title, but that does not work. Please see below for the two instances of code that I assume need to be combined in some way.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only handling single-cell updates
    
    HandleMultiSelect Target  'call the first action
    
    ShowHideColumns Target    '...then the next action
    
End Sub

Sub HandleMultiSelect(Target As Range)
    'do your multi-select list handling here
Dim rngDropdown As Range
Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim DelimiterType As String
DelimiterType = ", "
Dim DelimiterCount As Integer
Dim TargetType As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr() As String
 
If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
 
Set rngDropdown = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitError
 
If rngDropdown Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
 
TargetType = 0
    TargetType = Destination.Validation.Type
    If TargetType = 3 Then  ' is validation type is "list"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newValue = Destination.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = Destination.Value
        Destination.Value = newValue
        If oldValue <> "" Then
            If newValue <> "" Then
                If oldValue = newValue Or oldValue = newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") Or oldValue = newValue & DelimiterType Then ' leave the value if there is only one in the list
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, DelimiterType, "")
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue) Or InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & DelimiterType) Or InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue & DelimiterType) Then
                    arr = Split(oldValue, DelimiterType)
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(newValue, arr, 0)) = 0 Then
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                        Else:
                    Destination.Value = ""
                    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(i) <> newValue Then
                        Destination.Value = Destination.Value & arr(i) & DelimiterType
                    End If
                    Next i
                Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - Len(DelimiterType))
                End If
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, newValue, "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                Else
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                End If
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) ' remove extra commas and spaces
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""))
                If Destination.Value <> "" Then
                    If Right(Destination.Value, 2) = DelimiterType Then  ' remove delimiter at the end
                        Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - 2)
                    End If
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, DelimiterType) = 1 Then ' remove delimiter as first characters
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "", 1, 1)
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) = 1 Then
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "", 1, 1)
                End If
                DelimiterCount = 0
                For i = 1 To Len(Destination.Value)
                    If InStr(i, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                        DelimiterCount = DelimiterCount + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                If DelimiterCount = 1 Then ' remove delimiter if last character
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "")
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
 
exitError:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
End Sub

Sub ShowHideColumns(Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row = 8 Then
        If Target.Value = [D10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("F:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("D:E").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [F10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:E").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("H:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("F:G").Hidden = False
            
         ElseIf Target.Value = [H10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:G").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("J:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("H:I").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [J10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:I").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("L:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("J:K").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [L10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:K").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("N:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("L:M").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [N10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:M").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("P:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("N:O").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [P10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:O").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("R:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("P:Q").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [R10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:Q").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("T:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("R:S").Hidden = False
                  
        ElseIf Target.Value = [T10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:S").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("V:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("T:U").Hidden = False
            
         ElseIf Target.Value = [V10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:U").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("X:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("V:W").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [X10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:W").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("Z:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("X:Y").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [Z10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:Y").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AB:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("Z:AA").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AB10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AA").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AD:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AB:AC").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AD10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AC").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AF:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AD:AE").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AF10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AE").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AH:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AF:AG").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AH10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AG").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AJ:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AH:AI").Hidden = False
                  
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AJ10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AI").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AL:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AJ:AK").Hidden = False
            
         ElseIf Target.Value = [AL10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AK").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AN:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AL:AM").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AN10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AM").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AP:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AN:AO").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AP10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AO").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AR:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AP:AQ").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AR10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AQ").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AT:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AR:AS").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AT10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AS").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AV:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AT:AU").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AV10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AU").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AX:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AV:AW").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AX10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AW").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AZ:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AX:AY").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [AZ10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:AY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BB:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("AZ:BA").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BB10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BA").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BD:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BB:BC").Hidden = False
                  
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BD10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BC").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BF:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BD:BE").Hidden = False
            
         ElseIf Target.Value = [BF10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BE").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BH:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BF:BG").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BH10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BG").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BJ:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BH:BI").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BJ10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BI").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BL:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BJ:BK").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BL10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BK").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BN:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BL:BM").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BN10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BM").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BP:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BN:BO").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BP10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BO").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BR:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BP:BQ").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BR10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BQ").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BT:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BR:BS").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BT10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BS").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BV:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BT:BU").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BV10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BU").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BX:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BV:BW").Hidden = False
                  
        ElseIf Target.Value = [BX10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BW").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BZ:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BX:BY").Hidden = False
            
         ElseIf Target.Value = [BZ10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:BY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CB:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("BZ:CA").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CB10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CA").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CD:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CB:CC").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CD10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CC").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CF:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CD:CE").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CF10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CE").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CH:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CF:CG").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CH10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CG").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CJ:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CH:CI").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CJ10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CI").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CL:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CJ:CK").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CL10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CK").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CN:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CL:CM").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CN10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CM").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CP:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CN:CO").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CP10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CO").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CR:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CP:CQ").Hidden = False
                  
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CR10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CQ").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CT:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CR:CS").Hidden = False
            
         ElseIf Target.Value = [CT10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CS").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CV:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CT:CU").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CV10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CU").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CX:CY").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CV:CW").Hidden = False
            
        ElseIf Target.Value = [CX10].Value Then
            Application.Columns("D:CW").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("CX:CY").Hidden = False
              
        ElseIf Target.Value = "SHOW ALL" Then
            Application.Columns("ZZ").Hidden = True
            Application.Columns("D:CY").Hidden = False
        
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining multiple actions triggered by a worksheet change basically looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only handling single-cell updates
    
    HandleMultiSelect Target  'call the first action
    
    ShowHideColumns Target    '...then the next action
    
End Sub

Sub HandleMultiSelect(Target As Range)
    'do your multi-select list handling here
End Sub

Sub ShowHideColumns(Target As Range)
    'do your column hide/show here
End Sub
```

Edit: here's how you could modify the hide/show code (untested)

```vb
Sub ShowHideColumns(Target As Range)
    Dim v, arr, el, m, rngHdr As Range
    
    If Target.Address <> Me.Range("C8").Address Then Exit Sub
    
    v = Target.Value
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'nothing to do ?
    
    Set rngHdr = Me.Range("D10:CY10")
    
    rngHdr.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' first show all columns
    
    arr = Split(v, ",") 'an array of selected value
    
    For Each el In arr  'check each value in the array
        If v = "SHOW ALL" Then
            rngHdr.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Me.Columns("ZZ").Hidden = True
            Exit For
        Else
            m = Application.Match(el, rngHdr, 0) 'matches a column header?
            If Not IsError(m) Then   'if not an error then got a match
                rngHdr.Cells(m).Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'show two cols
            End If
        End If
    Next el
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "variable not defined" error that highlights the "Sub HandleMultiSelect (Target As Range) using the edited code above.

Comment: I also just realized that my current ShowHideColumns work isn't going to work because 1. The list would need to have it "contain" and not "equal" a certain value and 2. The current code has it hiding all but the column selected in the list. If two are on the list, then that code would contradict.

Comment: Your code uses `Destination` as the range variable name, and not `Target`.  For the column hiding - hide the whole set of columns and then loop over the selected values and unhide the matches.

Comment: I replaced Destination with Target and that did not seem to work. I'm not sure how to do the looping over selected values portion either for the column hiding.

Comment: Appreciate the update. I'll give it a shot.